# How to create a command line simulator GUI for C++

Tags: c++, cmd, simulation

I'm looking into developing a text based game about cyber security akin to hackRUN or uplink but I have no experience with GUI programming and I doubt anyone in my family would want to learn how to make and run a .cpp file. So I need to create a GUI featuring a custom command-line akin to Linux or windows "cmd". Is there any resources available in that area?

Comment: Are you talking about a GUI mimicking the looks of a command line interface, or a command line interface that can mimic certain aspects of GUI?

Comment: Also, your family doesn't have to compile the source code to run the program do they? You can always just give them the binary...

Comment: Yeah you can do this easily via Visual studios if you want it to be windows only, then the next best thing I wuld say to look into is GTK+ which is cross platform and a little more difficult to use

Comment: What is your actual problem, What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: My problem was that I am competent in programming logic but I have no idea where to start with GUI's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a textbox control that's the size of the entire window, and customize it to make it look like a console. For example, set the background to black, the color of the letters to white, etc.

How you create that textbox depends on what UI framework you're using. For C++ there's MFC or the managed WinForms, or you could create the UI part in C# using WPF and use C++/CLI as a bridge between C++ and C#. But if you want to make it work on both Windows and Linux you can use wxWidgets or Qt.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great place for me to start. Much Appreciated!

Comment: Unless the requirement is to provide a GUI that looks like a console (rather than a console that looks like a console), then this will put a lot of GUI messing about before any real work starts. By all means do this later, when you have a working game. In your comment on my answer you mention this is an exercise to learn C++; with WinForms and MFC you will just learn some annoying Windows APIs, not necessarily C++ itself. They are also neither best practices these days, nor are the online tutorials going to be in C++11, which should be your starting point as a beginner. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a commandline by reading a line from the user and splitting on the first space (Python/pseudocode*):

```
for line in raw_input():
    command,arguments = line.split(' ',1)
```

For example `read book` is the command `read` with the argument `book`.

Then you can process the command they gave using your own logic. The advantage of this approach is that you can just run your game via a shortcut on the desktop (whether linux or windows) and the OS console will support the interaction.

There is a class of games called 'text adventure' games, which were popular back when graphics were limited or nonexistent, which you may find particularly relevant. Consider using an existing text adventure engine so that you can concentrate on the game itself rather than the mechanics of text entry and parsing.

* Consider writing this in Python or a similar scripting language, as they provide straightforward handling of strings etc. You are unlikely to need the raw power and complexity of C++ for a commandline-style family game.

Comment: I appreciate your advice, though I want to do it in C++ mainly to improve my skills in that language since I am studying that language this semester. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user1803796: It's best to include all the relevant information in the question; that should help you get the most useful answers. Often including less information will lead people to give more general answers, as happened here. The suggestion to read commands line by line from the prompt stands, though, as the alternative is to write a load of GUI rubbish just to give you the same box to type in.